# What is wrong with my AJAX jQuery function?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a function that does a simple call to a PHP file with a simple INSERT statement in it. When I click the corresponding button, the function does not even send the AJAX request or return false.

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_employee_submit').click(function() {
        var fname = $('#eie_fname').text();
        var lname = $('#eie_lname').text();
        var doNo = $('#eie_doNo').val();
        var emergency = 0;
        if($('#eie_emergency').is(':checked')) {
            emergency = 1;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/employee_information_entry.php",
            data: "fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&dono="+doNo+"&emergency="+emergency,
            success: function() {
                showMessage('employee_added');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT:

Instead of wasting more time trying to figure out what was wrong I went with @ThiefMaster's advice and used jquery.malsup.com/form. This is working correctly and is a lot let work.

Thanks for everyone's help. :)

Comment: Stupid question: do you have an element with id 'add_employee_submit' ? Anyway, try using the submit() event instead

Comment: The fact that `data` is a string and not an object is not a really good thing. This way *you* have to take care about escaping stuff - which is usually not what you want. So use an object instead: `data: {fname: fname, lname: lname, dono: doNo, emergency: emergency}`

Comment: Consider using http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ - it saves you lots of work if you have an actual form you want to ajaxify.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy  there is an element with id 'add_employee_submit'. It is an input:submit;

Comment: any error in firebug/developer console? have you tried debugging the js with one of the two?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks for the tip. I am somewhat new to jQuery and AJAX. I switched it over to that but still no luck.

Comment: @Bogdan Emil Mariesan There are no errors coming up. Because the return false does not happen, the page also refreshes so any error would be wiped. I will add in a break so I can double check. EDIT: There are no errors coming up.

Comment: @user1195653 have you tried adding a simple alert before binding the click event? perhaps your entire document.ready anonymous function is never firing?

Comment: I used ThiefMaster's advice and started using jquery.malsup.com/form It fixed my AJAX problem. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

The success function should have a response parameter i.e. your code would be like:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "scripts/employee_information_entry.php",
   data: "fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&dono="+doNo+"&emergency="+emergency,
   success: function(response) {
       showMessage('employee_added');
   }
   });
```

Also check if the various id's are present there or not.

**The best method to check is to use firebug/developer console to check what parameters are being sent and what are being received.**